Splitting data with powershell
I have a wonderful little script that returns just what I needed at the time. But things change and now I need to add to my script. My powershell skills are limited. I have done some searching but not come up with a solution. Probably because I don't know how to formulate a question that gets the right answer.
I have an Array that looks like this:



KEY
DATA




KEY-A
Name1;Name2;Name3


KEY-B



KEY-C
Name1



But I really need it to be:



KEY
DATA




KEY-A
Name1


KEY-A
Name2


KEY-A
Name3


KEY-C
Name1



I'm thinking a foreach and a text split, but I can not get my brain to tell my fingers how to get started.
I tried reading up on foreach and (text)split I just seam to have hit a writers block on something that is very likely to be super simple.
As requested the code that gives my current data. I didn't add this because I didn't think it relevant for the solution.
$tempcontent = $webrequscontent.Content | ConvertFrom-Json


if($tempcontent.total -eq 0){
    $exportdata = #foreach ($obj in $tempcontent.issues) 
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            key = ""
            data = " "
            }
}

else {
    $exportdata = foreach ($obj in $tempcontent.issues) 
    {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            key = $obj.key
            Data = (($obj.fields.customfield_16170 | Select-String -Pattern $pattern -AllMatches).Matches.value) -join ';'
            }
    }
}

# convert objects to csv
$exportData | Export-CSV "H:\list.csv" -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation 



It sounds like you already have code what outputs the data you have so far? Why don't you show this code?

Added code. removed the web request part because it is internal and would not add any value to the code for testing or other wise. I'll be adding a csv file too.

With a quick look to it you just need a nested loop inside your foreach loop and iterate over $obj.key.

Provided your data is in same table format as $ArrayData, this simple foreach loop will work.
# Create your Json Table Example
$ArrayData = @(
[pscustomobject]@{Key = 'KEY-A' ;Data = 'Name1;Name2;Name3'}
[pscustomobject]@{Key = 'KEY-B' ;Data = ''}
[pscustomobject]@{Key = 'KEY-C' ;Data = 'Name1'}
)

# Format new pscustomobject and output to host
Foreach ($Array in $ArrayData){
    foreach ($Item in ($Array.Data -split ";")){
        [pscustomobject]@{Key = $Array.Key  ;Data = $Item}
    }
}


A sample of the JSON(or of the resulting object) would help but I think what you need is this:
$exportData = if ($tempcontent.total -eq 0) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        # unless you prefer using $null or have some specific need, like whitespaces
        # [string]::Empty should be better for... well, empty strings.
        key  = [string]::Empty
        data = [string]::Empty
    }
}
else {
    foreach ($obj in $tempcontent.issues) {
        $obj.data -split ';' | ForEach-Object {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                key  = $obj.key
                Data = (($obj.fields.customfield_16170 | Select-String -Pattern $pattern -AllMatches).Matches.value) -join ';'
            } 
        }
    }
} 

